# How can I connect to my server over the internet?

Tags: server

I downloaded Ubuntu server and set it up in a virtual machine, in settings under **network** on the virtual machine I made it a bridged adapter. I got my server up and running and I could connect to it in putty, filezilla (ftp) and by typing in my ip address in to the web browser (pulled up the apache start page). But I went somewhere else with a laptop and tried to connect to it (I also tried with my phone [not connected to wifi]) and it wouldn't connect so I am assuming that it is just under my local wifi.

Does anyone know how I can get it to go on the internet so I could connect to it not being on my home wifi? Thanks in advance and I hope this makes sense! I'm new to Ubuntu.

Comment: You need to set up "port forwarding" on your network gateway device (your "router") for the ports the server is listening on to direct that traffic to your server's LAN IP address.

Comment: See for example [What is port forwarding and what is it used for?](http://superuser.com/a/284073/549309)

Comment: I was told that if i wanted to run a ubuntu server i would need to have a server os and if i tried to do this on my pc (runing windows 10) it would crash